# Is it worth using rdtsc() for speed measurements?

Tags: c++, performance, tsc, measurement, rdtsc

I have 4 test functions - foo1(), foo2(), foo3() and foo4().
For measurements I use following program:

```
unsigned __int64 start;
unsigned __int64 stop;
unsigned __int64 sum;
unsigned __int64 orig;

sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    start = __rdtsc();
    foo1();
    stop = __rdtsc();
    sum += (stop - start);
}
orig=sum;
cout << "foo1() \taverage: " << (sum / 10000.0) << ", \tratio: " << ((double)orig / sum) << endl << endl;

sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    start = __rdtsc();
    foo2();
    stop = __rdtsc();
    sum += (stop - start);
}
cout << "foo2() \taverage: " << (sum / 10000.0) << ", \tratio: " << ((double)orig / sum) << endl << endl;
```

And so on, for foo3() and foo4().

I have this log on console:

```
foo1()      average: 401495,        ratio: 1
foo2()      average: 24251.2,       ratio: 16.5557
foo3()      average: 11497.7,       ratio: 34.9195
foo4()      average: 7439.06,       ratio: 53.9713
```

Does this mean that using foo4 () ~50 times faster (in real time) than foo1 ()?

OR does this mean that foo4() is DEFINITELY better in performance than foo1()?

Comment: When you benchmark, do you make sure that CPU frequency stays constant?

Comment: What would be the result if you execute the `foo` functions in an interleaved way (ie. in the same loop)? I also advise you to throw away the first iterations to reduce possible biases (eg. the impact of the memory/cache latency on the first call). Moreover, computing the standard deviation of the timings (and not just the mean) could help you to track possible benchmarking/performance issues and could also provide hints on whether you can safely compare the averages or not.

Answer (score 1):

"*faster (in real time)*" and "*better in performance*" are equivalent in a single-threaded, uncontended context, provided the measurement is correct.

From the looks of it, a 50x speedup measurement is a sure sign that the function is faster, and thus better, than the baseline.

BUT before you conclude:

1. Wrap your code into another outer loop, and loop for at least a couple of hundred milliseconds, throwing out the results of the first 200 ms, then take the *average* of the remaining measurements. This is especially important if the functions under test access memory. Memory caching effects can account for 100x+ elapsed time difference.
2. Add a call to `_mm_lfence()` after each `foo` invocation to ensure all of its instructions have retired before taking the clock measurement.

Microbenchmarking is hard; this often means that some functions can be meaningfully measured only in combination, also the amount of data processed should be roughly equivalent to a real-life scenario.